# control number of concurrent actions allowed to run dynamically c c++

Tags: c++, concurrency, semaphore

need to find a way to control number of actions that can enter the critical section. The number of actions can be updated by user in run-time.
e,g if there are 1000 actions, user can choose to have 1 action run at a time, so it would be sequential (e.g using mutex), each 1000 action needs to grab the mutex first.  the other case is allowing 500 action run at a time (e.g. using semaphore with initial value of 500). 
the problem is is there a way to control this value N (1 or 500) actions at run time (semaphore won't help as can't modify the initial value and don't know how many actions ready to enter)

Comment: There is no law that makes it illegal for you to create a counter protected by a mutex, initialize it with any value, and then implement a semaphore yourself, that atomically decrements the counter if it's not zero yet and then immediately returns, or waits until another thread increments the counter sufficiently for the current thread to now acquire the resource.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What is your question?

Comment: could you elaborate on the possible solution?

Comment: thanks. so the counter is for the maximum number of actions allowed at any time? and that can be updated if user decides on a new value?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 entities here

- Number of currently running job
- Maximum number of jobs allowed to run

You can make both variables `std::atomic_int` to allow modification from multiple threads.

Next use [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) coupled with `std::mutex`.

The pseudocode idea is

```
wait on condition variable while num_jobs_running >= num_allowed
++num_jobs_running
release the mutex
do the job
--num_jobs_running
notify condition variable
```